# AS3 Duplicate Function Definition with the getter/setter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using the following code:

```
public function get isMixerPopupVisible():Boolean{
    return (this._isMixerPopupVisible);
}
public function set isMixerPopupVisible(_arg1:Boolean):void{
    var _local2:Object = this._isMixerPopupVisible;
    if (_local2 !== _arg1){
        this._isMixerPopupVisible = _arg1;
        this.dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, "isMixerPopupVisible", _local2, _arg1));
    };
}
```

I'm trying to make this property bindable so that I can use the `ChangeWatcher.Watch` method with it, however, when I try to add in the `[Bindable]` tag just like this:

```
[Bindable]
public function get isMixerPopupVisible():Boolean{
    return (this._isMixerPopupVisible);
}
public function set isMixerPopupVisible(_arg1:Boolean):void{
    var _local2:Object = this._isMixerPopupVisible;
    if (_local2 !== _arg1){
        this._isMixerPopupVisible = _arg1;
        this.dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, "isMixerPopupVisible", _local2, _arg1));
    };
}
```

I get the error `Error: Duplicate function definition.` on the setter. Why is this? I'm using FlashDevelop with AS3 and Flex 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setter/getter` looks like as automatically generated by `mxmlc` for property:

```
[Bindable]
public var isMixerPopupVisible
```

It's an `mxmlc` itself who should insert code for dispatching `PropertyChangeEvent` with old/new value, try a simple class property as I showed in the example above.

Note:
If you want to find the reason what exactly cause that error in your case (without any modifications) add compiler flag

```
keep-generated-actionscript=true|false
```

and check what you have (I believe you will find that `Duplicate function definition.`)